TS1239: Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression when using inversify and custom lazyLoading function
Have created the custom lazyLoading function in utils.ts that makes lazyServiceidentifier of inversify , when I try to consume the lazyLoading function in one the other service file within same project it gives
Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression.
The runtime will invoke the decorator with 3 arguments, but the decorator expects 2.ts(1239)
Below is the code of lazyLoading in utils.ts
 import { inject ,LazyServiceIdentifer} from 'inversify';

export function lazyLoading(serviceIdentifier: ()=> symbol): PropertyDecorator { 
  return function(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol):void{
    inject(serviceIdentifier)(target, propertyKey as string);
    const id = serviceIdentifier();
    Object.defineProperty(target,propertyKey,{
       configurable: true,
       enumerable: true,
       get: function() {
        const lazyServiceIdentifer = new LazyServiceIdentifer<any>(() => this.container.get(id))
        return lazyServiceIdentifer;
       }
    })
  }

and in the xy.ts file I tried to import and use it as given below  and it is here that it gives the resolve signature of parameter error when using @lazyLoading.
import { lazyLoading } from "../utils/util";
 constructor(
    @lazyLoading(()=>TYPES.OrchestratorService) _orchestratorService: OrchestratorService
  ) {
    
    this.orchestratorService = _orchestratorService;
  }

Had setup the tsConfig as below
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "types": ["reflect-metadata","jest"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "@types"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}


need to use lazyLoading for solving the circular dependency issue and have tried to use lazyInject as well that inversify provides with inversify-binding-decorators even in that case was getting the same issue. Need to understand why this issue ? and how to fix it
TS version used is ^4.7.4.

Hi, did you managed to find a solution?
